# Dynamicly creating elements inside pug(jade)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to dynamicly create elements inside pug template.

I retrieve an informations from database using basic command

```
 db.component.findAll().then(function(component){
    res.render('stock' ,{ table:component})
  })
```

the template that the content is supposed to be created is

```
  .tbl-content
    table(cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', border='0')
      tbody
       - row in table
            tr
                td= "#{row.name}"
                td= "#{row.storage}"
```

I have checked the syntax and it should be correct , but the result is complete wrong. It takes `row in table` as string e.g content and show it on page , same with `"#{row.name}"` and `"#{row.storage}"`

Am i using some outdated syntax  or is my approach completely wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your used syntax seems to be wrong if you're using the default `pug` template engine for Node.js

You can make it work by:

```
.tbl-content
    table(cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0', border='0')
      tbody
       each row in table
            tr
                td= row.name
                td= row.storage
```

Explaned in more detail in the documentation: 
https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

My complete simple Node.js test file with which I did the successfull testing was:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

var component = [
    {name:'myName', storage:'myStorage'},
    {name:'myName2', storage:'myStorage2'}
];
app.get('/table', function (req, res) {
    res.render('stock' ,{ table:component});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

It results in the response:

```
<div class="tbl-content">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>myName</td><td>myStorage</td></tr>
   <tr><td>myName2</td><td>myStorage2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```